# Measuring the spacing of data over a fixed range

Tags: math, mathematical-optimization

I am experimenting with using [Opt4J](http://opt4j.sourceforge.net/) to solve an optimization problem. The optimization problem involves a collection of dates, and I need an objective function that favors solutions whose dates are evenly spaced over a fixed range.

What would be a good objective function for this?

**Thoughts so far...**

I thought taking the intervals between all the neighboring dates and defining my objective function as the statistical variance of those intervals. In a perfect solution, all the intervals would be equal, so their variance would be zero. The more spread out the intervals, the worse the solution, and the more positive their variance.

But I noticed that there are a couple problems with variance.

1. If the dates are spaced evenly but they aren't spread across the fixed range, the objective function still rates them quite highly.
2. If I add another piece to the function that penalizes solutions without dates close to the boundaries of the fixed range, I'm not sure how to "balance" that with the variance...

Comment: can't you add the date range as constraints?  That's how it's usually done.  If these are not hard constraints, then you need to find a scale to weight it  and add to the objective term. That depends on your problem.

Comment: Hi @karakfa. The date range already _is_ a constraint. The problem is that solutions where the dates are evenly spaced but really tightly clustered (say in the middle of the range, or at either end) are still being considered good solutions. I need the dates to occupy the whole range.

Comment: add the distance from either end to the variance computation, which will take care of it.  So if you have 2 points for example, compute the variance of  3 intervals, after sorting: [B-P1], [P1-P2], [P2-E].

Comment: If the date range and number of dates to be fitted between them is known in advance, can you calculate the 'ideal' dates before your optimisation and then add terms into your objective to penalise deviation from those dates.